# Getting Objects with urllib2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, get, urllib2

I have two GAE apps working in conjunction. One holds an object in a database, the other gets that object from the first app. Below I have the bit of code where the first app is asked for and gives the Critter Object. I am trying to access the first app's object via urllib2, is this really possible? I know it can be used for json but can it be used for objects?

Just for some context I am developing this as a project for a class. The students will learn how to host a GAE app by creating their critters. Then they will give me the url for their critters and my app will use the urls to collect all of their critters then put them into my app's world.

I've only recently heard about pickle, have not looked into yet, might that be a better alternative?

critter.py:

```
class Access(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        creature = CritStore.all().order('-date').get()
        if creature:
            stats = loads(creature.stats)
            return SampleCritter(stats)
        else:
            return SampleCritter()
```

map.py:

```
class Out(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        url = self.request.POST['url']#from a simple html textbox
        critter = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        ...work with critter as if it were the critter object...
```

Comment: If you have have two separate appengine apps utilizing the same data, you may well be in breach of the terms and conditions.   Secondly if you want to get datastore entities from a different datastore you could always use the cloud datastore.

Comment: How do I access the information from the cloud datastore?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/datastore/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use pickle.

Here is some sample code to transfer an entity, including the key :

```
entity_dict = entity.to_dict() # First create a dict of the NDB entity
entity_dict['entity_ndb_key_safe'] = entity.key.urlsafe() # add the key of the entity to the dict
pickled_data = pickle.dumps(entity_dict, 1) # serialize the object
encoded_data = base64.b64encode(pickled_data) # encode it for safe transfer
```

As an alternative for urllib2 you can use the GAE urlfetch.fetch()

In the requesting app you can :

```
entity_dict = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(encoded_data))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm just learning GAE, so I have absolutely no idea what is going on here. Could you please elaborate. What do you mean by the entity here? Why do I need the key? what is the base64.b64encode(pickled_data) doing?

Comment: I advise to follow the getting started with python : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction and you will find the entity. Wikipedia : Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs to be transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data. This is to ensure that the data remain intact without modification during transport.

Comment: 2 more questions if you dont mind, because this is quite interesting. will .to_dict() handle the functions? For instance if my entity has a move() function where it's x and y will be added to, will that be preserved? Second why does the key matter, and why does it have to be urlsafe()?

Comment: NO, to_dict makes a dict of the entity properties. Pickle will serialize the object. If you do not need the key : skip the key and the to_dict. urlsafe means : you can use they urlsafe_key as part of an url : example : "http://example.com/this is not an url safe key" because it has spaces.